# Why does grep stop working after "Permission Denied"?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I executed a very simple `grep`:

```
grep -r "someSimpleWord" .
```

Now, there is one directory which contains some files producing some messages like

```
grep: path/to/some/unpermitted/file: Permission denied
```

After printing those messages `grep` just stops doing anything. It does not return nor does it continue searching (looking at `top` output there is no `grep` after the messages have been printed).
When I add

```
--exclude-dir="path/to/some/unpermitted"
```

grep works as expected again.

Since there is no error message I would consider that a bug in `grep` but that feels very unlikely. What am I missing here?

I am on Ubuntu 12.02.

Edit: Think of using the `-s` option (suppressing all error messages), which would leave you with an empty line and a grep doing nothing. So you wait and wait because, well, that just could take a while.

Comment: Hard to tell, but if you install the `strace` tool and run `strace grep -r "someSimpleWord" .` you can see what grep is doing.

Comment: Without further knowledge of your directory structure, the most likely explanation is that `path/to/some/unpermitted`, besides containing some unpermitted files, also contains (many/big) files which you _are_ permitted to read; and grep is just taking a very long time to scan those.

Comment: What version of grep do you use? My gnu grep 2.10 continues after printing permisison denied messages.

Comment: @Ruud the directory is only 12kB big, containing 88 files.

Comment: @chaos the version is gnu grep 2.10. I should add that the files causing the Permission denied messages are special devices. In my opinion that should be no problem, though.

Comment: @nos the last line of `strace` reads: `read(3,` Then it stops. The lines before are: `open("./path to unpermitted/ptmx", O_RDONLY) = 3
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0` Maybe there is a problem with that ptmx (which is a character special)?

Comment: @Callahan Sounds like you're in an uninterruptible sleep (state D). Can you provide the output of: `ps -eo stat,pid,cmd | grep grep`? Is that folder a mounted nfs drive?

Comment: @chaos the output (while my grep is running): `S    24094 grep --color=auto -r --exclude=./path/to/unpermitted/ptmx someSimpleWord .
S+   24101 grep --color=auto grep
`. The folder should not be on a nfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the file where grep stops, `./path to unpermitted/ptmx` indicates it's a perhaps a special device file such as a pty mux, normally only found in the /dev/ directory. grep will open that, but the device doesn't supply any data, so grep blocks until data becomes available(which is never).

Use the `-D skip` argument to grep.

```
-D ACTION, --devices=ACTION
   If an input file is a device, FIFO or socket, use ACTION to process it.  
   By default, ACTION is read, which means that devices are read just as if they  
   were ordinary files.  If ACTION is skip, devices are silently skipped.
```

Comment: Nice clarification. I was not aware that devices should be treated carefully while searching. I think the default action for devices should be `skip` but, well. Anyway, that behavior is certainly no bug (: